# Getting count of records in vf page

Tags: visualforce

I have created 1 object application which is related to contact. i.e Lookup relationship b/w contact and application.
Created Contact field as lookup on application object 
In vf page i want to show all contacts and count of application per contact besides contact name.
I am trying out this code

[image]

Class code:

```
public with sharing class theController 
{
    Set<ID> ContactIds = new Set<ID>();
    Set<ID> UserIds = new Set<ID>();

    public Contact contact{get;set;}

    public List<Contact> lstContact{get;set;}
    public List<User> lstUser{get;set;}

    public theController()
    {
            lstUser = [Select Id,ContactId from user where IsActive=true and IsPortalEnabled = true];

            for(User user: lstUser)
            {
                contactIds.add(user.ContactId);
                UserIds.add(user.Id);
            }

            lstContact=[Select Name,AccountId from Contact where Id IN: contactIds];

            if(lstContact != null && lstContact.size()>0)
            {
                this.contact = lstContact[0];
            }

            Integer countapplication =[Select count() from Application__c where Contact__c IN : contactIds];
            system.debug('## countapplication' + countapplication);
    }
}
```

No getting the count of application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public  Map<string,integer> ansalpha {
get {
   AggregateResult[] groupedResults=[SELECT COUNT(),Contact__c FROM  Application__c where Contact__c IN : contactIds GROUPBY Contact__c];

  Map<string,integer> mapCntIdByapplicationCount=new Map<string,integer>();

     for(AggregateResult a:groupedResults){
         mapCntIdByapplicationCount.put(String.valueof(a.get('Contact__c')),integer.valueof(string.valueof(a.get('expr0'))));
  }

   return mapCntIdByapplicationCount; 
  }
 set;
}
```

You can use aggregate SOQL to accomplish this as shown above .Form a map and then you can get from the map for your visualforce

```
<apex:repeat value="{!lstContact}" var="c">
  <apex:outputField value="{!c.Name}"/>
  <apex:outputText value="Value="{!ansalpha[c.Id]}" />"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the child relationship is called `Applications__c` you should do this as part of your  main query on the Contact object:

```
lstContact = [Select Name, AccountId, (select Id from Applications__r) from Contact where Id IN: contactIds];
```

And then in your page you can simply use the size of the returned list for each:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!lstContact}" var="c">
  <apex:outputField value="{!c.Name}"/>
  <apex:outputText value="{!Floor(c.Applications__r.Size)}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

The reason your code isn't working is that you're just getting the total count of applications for *all* of the contacts being displayed.